When simulating phonons of metals, is LO-TO splitting still relevant?
I was starting to approach the simulation of phonon dispersion of metallic alloys, hence I was interested in understanding what kind of phenomenon I should expect, in a general sense. For instance, is it LO-TO splitting still relevant?
Of course, I only need to be oriented on what to expect, I know that getting deeper in that field is my responsibility. Anyhow, any advice is strongly appreciated!

+1 but I reduced it to 1 question.
